# How to format moment date without considering user's timezone?

Tags: javascript, angular, timezone, momentjs, moment-timezone

**Scenario:**
A user selects a date from +01:00 timezone as 2023-08-26.
But when another user from +09:00 timezone view the date it displays as 2023-08-27.

I have a date pipe to format dates into M/D/YYYY format. Value is passing to my dateFormat pipe as a moment object like below.

[image]

Is there a way to get the date without converting it to user's timezone?

**What I tried:**

const extractedDate = moment(value).toDate();

But if i use above method value is getting converted to user's local timezone.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `moment-timezone`, you can set the default timezone so that date objects are always in the same timezone.

```js
const moment = require("moment-timezone")
moment.tz.setDefault("UTC");

const epochDate = 1692979660;
const extractedDate = moment(epochDate, "X").toDate();
```